# What does this semantic do?

Tags: syntax, computer-science, semantics

I am learning semantics through the While programming language at my university.

**The paper:** Chapter 3 The While programming language. Hilary term 2012

Here is an educational institution with the link [here](http://profs.sci.univr.it/~merro/files/WhileExtra_l.pdf)

**Question:** I do not understand what **page 4** is trying to explain, at this part: `s[k 7→ n](l) = ...`
[picture of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyRZp.png)

**I think:** if the memory location L is the same as the memory location K then return the numeral n, otherwise do s(L) to return whatever numeral is in memory location L.

I am very sorry about the tags but this topic is so advanced I struggle to know what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked with my professor and my original thinking was correct, here is the answer copied from the question above:

> If the memory location L is the same as the memory location K then
>   return the numeral n, otherwise do s(L) to return whatever numeral is
>   in memory location L.

Thanks to all of the down voters :-).